# Using variables in where clause of SQL statement in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlexception, where-in

I want to select some rows from my database based on the values stored in my variables (`supp_rec` array). I have used tips on similar previous post/question. However, I am still having some error messages. The code snippet is below:

```
waiting_time = dbMngr.runQuery( "SELECT " + "ExpectedWaitingTime" + " FROM Student" +     "where deptID = '" + supp_rec[1] + "' and weight = '" + supp_rec[2] + "'");
prob = PoisonModel(Phase3GUI.existence_time -     Long.parseLong(waiting_time[0]),2,Phase3GUI.existence_time);
if (prob > 0.5)
 {
    dbMngr.execUpdate( "DELETE " + " FROM Student" + "where deptID NOT IN" + supp_rec[1] + " and weight NOT IN" + supp_rec[2]);
 }+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The error message is below:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'deptID NOT IN1 and weight NOT IN8' at line 1 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '1' and weight = '8'' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Please I will appreciate any help on how to solve these errors. Thank you.

Comment: Use placeholders. Update the code to that *first* and then ask again. In any case, if you *look at the actual SQL text* you'll immediately see several syntax problems.

Comment: This is a very messy way of doing things.  Instead of "SELECT "+ variable " rest of statement;" try String.format("SELECT %s rest of statement;", variable);

Comment: @735Tesla But using `String.format` for arbitrary values is a [poor way](http://bobby-tables.com/) of handling the overall task here.

Comment: Also I don't know if you wanted it this way but enclosing `ExpectedWaitingTime` in quotes makes it interpret the string letter ally instead of looking at the variable's value. If it isn't a variable, why not just put it all in one string?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using prepared statements...

Comment: @user2864740 but is he using only arbitrary data?

Comment: @735Tesla It honestly doesn't matter. Teach good techniques that can be consistently applied.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql error message is

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'deptID NOT
>   **IN1** and weight NOT **IN8**' at line 1 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

So, without the space, mysql tries to parse **IN1** as a part of it's syntax & hence the query fails. It should be **IN 1** where **IN** is valid SQL token.

To correct this, add a space after **IN** in your statement -

```
dbMngr.execUpdate( "DELETE " + " FROM Student" + "where deptID NOT IN " + supp_rec[1] + " and weight NOT IN " + supp_rec[2]);
```

EDIT : Noticed that you're passing a single value for **NOT IN**. In that case, it should be just **!=** operator.

```
dbMngr.execUpdate( "DELETE " + " FROM Student" + "where deptID != " + supp_rec[1] + " and weight != " + supp_rec[2]);
```

Comment: There are still errors. (At least one missing space, and I suspect that `supp_rec[x]` aren't valid as IN operators - in particular because I suspect they are missing parenthesis, but I'm not entirely sure what they are supposed to contain.)

Answer (score 1):

Added `()` between the variables content, spaces between them and formatted a little bit

```
dbMngr.execUpdate(String.format("DELETE FROM Student WHERE deptID NOT IN (%s) and weight NOT IN (%s)", supp_rec[1], supp_rec[2]));
```

**Additionally**, It's highly risky for you, not be using protections against [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a PreparedStatement.  The SQL will be much easier to read and you'll avoid most of these problems.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Error now resolved.